# Contribute Without delete Permission level

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-permission-level

I am having an issue with creating Contribute Without deleting the custom permission level. What I need is users should be able to do everything except deleting documents. They should be able to add, edit, create a view, update the view, pin to the top, and everything. The issue I have is with below custom permission the users still able to delete the documents.
[image]

Comment: Seems like users are having other permissions as well besides the above custom permission.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, I create a same custom permission level based on your screenshot, however I cannot reproduce your issue:
[image]

In my site, if "Delete items" has not been included, the delete items/documents option will miss in list or library.

Please make sure that users have only custom permission levels. If they have other higher-level permissions, the lower-level permissions will be overwritten.

Similar issue about "custom contribute permission without delete items" for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/436718/sharepoint-online-custom-permission.html